# Prolog: Arguments not sufficiently instantiated

Tags: prolog, instantiation-error

I am trying to compile and query this code:

```
    
got('no').

inMap(X,Y):- print("From inMap").

mask(1,3).
doctor(2,1).

verify(X,Y):-
    (inMap(X,Y), ((\+(got('mask'); got('vaccine')),farCovid(X,Y)); True), 
    (print(X), print(Y); True),
    (doctor(X,Y), print(X), print(Y); True)).
```

When my query is:
?- verify(2,1).

It returns:

```
"From inMap""From farCovid"2121
true .
```

But when my query is:
?- verify(1,1).

It returns:

```
"From inMap""From farCovid"11
ERROR: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated
ERROR: In:
ERROR:   [10] verify(1,1)
ERROR:    [9] <user>
```

Can somebody explain to me what is wrong here please, wasn't it supposed to pass in (1,1) in the second query to doctor(X,Y) and return false?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The cause is the `True` which is a variable. Use `true`. But all heavy usage of print is not what Prolog is about.

Comment: thanks a lot, I literally confused True in other programming languages and this one's.